# How to edit /proc/<pid>/limits file in linux?

Tags: linux, process, linux-kernel, coredump

I am trying to generate coredump for a particular pid. 
I tried to change the core file size limit using ulimit, but it will change only in /proc/self/limits ( which is for shell).

So how do i edit it for particular pid? 
  Bascially i have to change "Max core file size=unlimited"

Note:

1)Our linux version dont have prlimit.

2)Even the below command didnt help

```
     echo -n "Max core file size=unlimited:unlimited" > /proc/1/limits
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

prlimit

if you want to modify core_file limit, you can type

```
prlimit --pid ${pid} --core=soft_limit:hard_limit
```

the help page of prlimit is :

```
Usage:
 prlimit [options] [-p PID]
 prlimit [options] COMMAND

General Options:
 -p, --pid <pid>        process id
 -o, --output <list>    define which output columns to use
     --noheadings       don't print headings
     --raw              use the raw output format
     --verbose          verbose output
 -h, --help             display this help and exit
 -V, --version          output version information and exit

Resources Options:
 -c, --core             maximum size of core files created
 -d, --data             maximum size of a process's data segment
 -e, --nice             maximum nice priority allowed to raise
 -f, --fsize            maximum size of files written by the process
 -i, --sigpending       maximum number of pending signals
 -l, --memlock          maximum size a process may lock into memory
 -m, --rss              maximum resident set size
 -n, --nofile           maximum number of open files
 -q, --msgqueue         maximum bytes in POSIX message queues
 -r, --rtprio           maximum real-time scheduling priority
 -s, --stack            maximum stack size
 -t, --cpu              maximum amount of CPU time in seconds
 -u, --nproc            maximum number of user processes
 -v, --as               size of virtual memory
 -x, --locks            maximum number of file locks
 -y, --rttime           CPU time in microseconds a process scheduled
                        under real-time scheduling

Available columns (for --output):
 DESCRIPTION  resource description
    RESOURCE  resource name
        SOFT  soft limit
        HARD  hard limit (ceiling)
       UNITS  units

For more details see prlimit(1).
```

Answer (score 0):

I always do this with ulimit command:

```
$ ulimit -c unlimited
```

On my Linux distro (ubuntu 16.04), core files are left on this directory:

```
/var/lib/systemd/coredump/
```

If your distro is based on systemd, you can setup this directory by modifiying pattern on this file:

```
$ cat /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

Comment: but ulimit changes only the self proc limit which is shell in my case. I want to edit for PID 1.

Comment: Why you need this for PID 1? When you run a binary on a shell, that shell is responsible for processes started by it, so you shouldn't modify init process to dump core files. You should modify ulimit for the shell that starts your binary, before executing it.

Comment: I want to collect coredump from a board running on linux where PID 1 is parent for all processes.

Answer (score 0):

Please, read this info:

```
$ man 5 core
```

Check information related with /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern.

As suggested previously, you can define the directory where all your core files are dumped, modifying the content of this file with "echo" command. For example:

```
$ echo "/var/log/dumps/core.%e.%p" > /proc/sys/kernel/core_pattern
```

This will dump all cores on /var/log/dumps/core.%e.%p, where %e is pattern for the executable filename, and %p pattern for pid of dumped process.

Hopefully you can play with this to customize your own needs.